# Dual Monitors on a GeForce FX 5200

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have access to a desktop pc with a GeForce FX 5200 video card.

The ports on the back of the card are:

- VGA
- S-Video
- DVI

I would like to have a dual monitor setup with the VGA and DVI ports, but the NVIDIA control panel will **only** allow for a monitor on the VGA port and a TV on the S-Video port. It does not seem to recognize that there is a DVI port.

Is there a way to fix this, or should I just buy a new video card?

About the best explanation I can think of is the only combinations I can have are:

- S-Video and VGA
- S-Video and DVI

and not what I want:

- VGA and DVI

Comment: I assume you are on windows, but are you running the newest nvidia drivers? What happens when you connect two displays?

Comment: Troggy, yes running Windows XP with the newest driver from NVIDIA. I get no output from the DVI port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not recognizing there is a DVI port, I'd guess it's bad.  I'm running exactly the setup right now that you say you want on the same class card.  Try popping it into another machine or putting another card in.  Also, like Troggy commented, make sure you have the newest drivers.